# Infopath form 'Save' closes the form

Tags: infopath, save, close

On Infopath form: *Save* command saves *and closes* the form. Users want to be able to save form multiple times without closing it (the same way Excel and other Office Apps work). How can I change the default behavior?

Comment: Is this a custom form for a SharePoint list? Can you elaborate what you mean? Creating a button in InfoPath let's you set several rules/step of what to do on a button click. If you want it as a requirement to be able to save multiple times and then make a last save&close.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable default save button and create a new button on your custom form with save rule.

Hope this can help you.

1-Use File-->Form Options to hide default save button and ribbon.
[image]

2-You can use infopath ribbon and rule manager to add button and rules.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

if you don't want to close form, use "submit data" only.

Comment: Can you please provide with brief description, on how to create new button and hide the original one.

Comment: I modified the answer. Hope it helps. @AsadRefai